# How to apply ASP.NET EF Core Migrations during github actions on RDS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, entity-framework-core, github-actions, amazon-ecs

I have been searching for a while to solve the problem and could not find the best practice, but so far, I am stuck and I don't know what the best practice is to automatically apply EF Core migrations to my RDS PostgreSQL Database on AWS.

The RDS Database is not public but accessible from my EC2 Instance. In my GitHub Actions file, I create the Docker container, upload it to AWS ECR, and after this, I log into my EC2 Ubuntu instance, pull the Docker container from ECR, and run it. This all works, only the migration step is missing. Due to the fact that the RDS DB is not accessible from the outer world, the EC2 instance should do this, or do you have a better approach? I do not want to upload all my source code to my EC2 instance.

I found a really ugly approach which is currently in my mind: I have my main project which I call EFCoreBasic. Besides this project, I add another project I call MigrationHelper. This MigrationHelper Project copies the files from my Migration Folder and defines also how my Model is connecting to the DB. I don't know if this approach works

Then I write a step in my GitHub Actions YAML file that uploads the MigrationHelper Source Code Project with the Migration Folder to my EC2 instance. I connect to the EC2 instance via SSH and execute the `dotnet ef database update` to update my DB.

Here is my GitHub Actions YAML:

```yaml
name: Deploy to AWS ECR
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  AWS_REGION: eu-central-1
  ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME: ${{ secrets.ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME }}
  IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
  MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ secrets.MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}

jobs:
  builddockerimageanduploadtoecr:
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build the Docker image
        working-directory: .
        run: docker build --rm -t me/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }} .
      - name: Get AWS Permissions
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::${{ env.MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/CustomECRPowerAccess
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
      - name: Upload to ECR
        run: |
          aws ecr get-login-password --region ${{ env.AWS_REGION }} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${{ env.MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ env.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com
          docker tag me/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }} ${{ env.MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ env.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}
          docker push ${{ env.MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ env.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}

  backupdatabase:
    needs: builddockerimageanduploadtoecr
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Backup database
        run: echo "not implemented Backup database..."

  applyefcoremigrations:
    needs: builddockerimageanduploadtoecr
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Apply EF Core Migrations
        run: echo "not implemented Apply EF Core Migrations..."

  pullimagetoec2andrun:
    needs: applyefcoremigrations
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Pull image; start image
        env:
          EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY }}
          EC2_HOSTNAME: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOSTNAME }}
          EC2_USER_NAME: ${{ secrets.EC2_USER_NAME }}

        run: |
          echo "$EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key && chmod 600 private_key
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_key ${EC2_USER_NAME}@${EC2_HOSTNAME} '
              aws ecr get-login-password --region ${{ env.AWS_REGION }} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${{ env.MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ env.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com
              docker pull ${{ env.MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ env.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}
              docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
              sudo docker run --rm -p 80:80 -p 5001:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://+:5001 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 ${{ env.MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ env.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY_NAME }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}
              '
```